# What formal argument allow to pass from EL equations to gradient descent?

Tags: reference-request, calculus-of-variations, gradient-descent

Given a functional of the form

$$
J[y] = \int_{a}^b F(x,y,y')dx
$$

the EL equation is given by

$$
\frac{dJ}{dy} = \left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \right) F
$$

In applications however if often see the following rule for gradient descent

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t} y  = -\left( \frac{\partial}{\partial y} - \frac{d}{dx}\frac{\partial}{\partial y'} \right) F
$$

The questions isn't much about the formula per se, but how do we formalize the gradient descent in such case? I can't manage to find a proof or a derivation of the rule.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you mention one of such *applications*?

Comment: Noise removal in image processing. Like this guy: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29703/euler-lagrange-gradient-descent-heat-equation-and-image-denoising?rq=1

Comment: Doesn't the answer in that post solve your question as well?

Comment: No, because it seems to me is too short to get a proper insight. I don't know if for the name there's a method that might make it easier to look up.